# How to get tiny lines to swarm together into a circular pattern?

Tags: vector, patterns

Preferably using Adobe Animate or Illustrator.

Image taken from: https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html

[image]

Comment: Out of interest what's the end use? It looks like a wind or tide flow diagram?

Comment: I would say Mathematica!

Comment: I was curious about @joojaa answer and I found this: https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/ Looks cool.  It's paid, but they offer a 15-day trial

Comment: @Manly theres is even a mathematica.SE  and a image like that is called a vector plot

Comment: @Manly if your interested [here](https://pastebin.com/E2yrQUwZ) is code and  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCiyg.png) result

Comment: You can also use [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), which is Open Source, and plot a vector field (see an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240722/how-to-create-streamline-like-arrow-lines-in-gnuplot)). You can also consider to use [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) as well (an example [here](http://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Octave_Matlab_PlotApplication.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do that with  Adobe Animate or Illustrator but you could use [Processing](https://www.processing.org/).

Here's the code and the result:

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  noCursor();
}

void draw() {
  background(34,70,135); 

  stroke(200,75,130);
  strokeWeight(2);

  int resolution = 25;
  PVector attractor = new PVector(mouseX, mouseY);

  for (int x=0; x<width; x+=resolution) {
    for (int y=0; y<height; y+=resolution) {

      PVector v = getSpiralVector(x-attractor.x, y-attractor.y);

      v.normalize().mult(resolution/2);

      pushMatrix();
      translate(x, y);
      line( -v.x, -v.y, v.x, v.y);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }

  fill(255,50);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,200,200);
}

PVector getSpiralVector(float x, float y) {
  return  new PVector(y-x, -x-y);
}

void mouseClicked(){
  saveFrame(hour()+"_"+minute()+"_"+second()+".png");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Scripting this in illustrator would look much the same. So if you can do this in processing you should be able to do this with illustrators dcripting layer in a few hours of thinking about the datamodel. Good exercise to do.

Comment: How would this look in a fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/8pbsuscm/

Comment: You should convert it to Javascript and use p5.js, instead of Processing. If I have time today I will do it.